# How to GET a document from an index inside of an alias

Tags: elasticsearch

I have inserted a few of my indexes inside of an alias because I've updated the index mapping a few times. I am looking to query my indexes behind my alias for potential documents depending on the search criteria.

I've been querying using just indexes up until now, like so -

```js
  const { body: clientBody } = await client.search({
    index: 'my-index',
    filter_path: 'hits.hits._source',
    body: { query: { bool: esObject } },
    size: 10000,
  });
```

but as I now have multiple indexes I wish to query inside of my alias I have created (my-alias) this no longer works as needed. I've tried replacing the `index` for `alias` but this does not work. Is there something I'm missing?

How I've added my indexes to my alias.

```js
await client.indices.updateAliases(
{[
    {
      add: {
        index: 'my-index-1',
        alias: 'my-alias',
      },
    },
    {
      add: {
        index: 'my-index-2'
        alias: 'my-alias'
       },
     },
]});
```

Comment: You have several indices and added the same alias for all, now that you create a search query using that alias and return a document in any of the indices, is that it?

Comment: @rabbitbr yes, that's what I'm looking to do. I'll update my question above to show how I've added my indexes to my alias to clarify.

Comment: Run this command to see if the index is with the alias you created.: GET idx_example/_alias
Theoretically, it would be changing the name of the index by the alias in your code and so the results would be returned.

Comment: My project is using javascript to invoke the elasticsearch APIs. Is this just the _alias api you are using here?

Comment: You don't have access to Kibana's Dev Tools?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. Due to how the datastore was configured

Comment: Try this: client.cat.indices({ format: "JSON" }) and check if your indices are the alias.

Comment: Hi again @rabbitbr, turns out that the `index` that's in the npm package is actually used as the target. The documentation builds up the query like so: `/$encodeURIComponent(params.index.toString())}/search`. so using `index` as the `alias` works. Feel silly for not having tried it like so but I've finally realised what's going on a little more. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the nodejs package. The `index` will be used as the target, as we can see from [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/main/src/api/api/search.ts#L77-L80).

So the solution was to just change my index, and stop it pointing at 'my-index' but rather at 'my-alias' instead.

```js
  const { body: clientBody } = await client.search({
    index: 'my-alias',
    filter_path: 'hits.hits._source',
    body: { query: { bool: esObject } },
    size: 10000,
  });
```